# How do I create a navigation drawer which allows for input elements like textboxes and buttons with only HTML and css?

Tags: html, css, navigation-drawer

Good day

I usually build mobile apps on android studio but for a project I'm doing i'm required to build in cordova, that means HTML and css.

Now, I am trying to create a navigation drawer on a floating panel I have already created, i'm not sure how to go about doing it with pure html and css. I tried using select and and option tags but I need this navigation drawer to have input options like textboxes and buttons. And I understand select cannot be used with input options?
Can I please have some assistance.

Comment: A select button only has a list of options you can choose between. You probably want to have a container div that has its css set to display: none unless it is hovered or focuesed. That container will have all your inputs.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You may create two divs one named as "drawer" and other one as "drawer-content" and put "drawer-content" in "drawer". Set display of the drawer-content div to none, unless drawer is hovered.
You may use the following code and make changes according to your need:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.drawer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.drawer-content {
    display: none;
}

.drawer:hover .drawer-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="drawer">

        <a class="drawer">TUTORIALS</a>

        <div class="drawer-content">
        <input type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
        <a>HTML</a><br>
        <a>CSS</a><br>
        <a>Javascript</a><br>
        <a>JQuery</a><br>
        <a>Bootstrap</a><br>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```